# Microsoft Teams Search

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there a way to either save a chat session and name it so you can quickly access it without scrolling through a large amount of history, or do advanced searches. For example I'd like to return all teams chat history from a specific group for a specific date.

Not sure why the down votes, is the question not clear? Wrong place to ask this question?

We have group session chats we need to be able to easily access later, it's hard when you have to sift through a ton of data. We used to use camp fire where you could archive a chat session so you could easily pull it up when needed but we can't use camp fire anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft teams has already already have powerful search functionality where you can search anything irrespective of large amount of data. It can take you directly to the archived conversation if your search criteria is matched.

Please look at the official MSFT link:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/search-for-messages-people-and-files-in-teams-4a351520-33f4-42ab-a5ee-5fc0ab88b263

In addition: you can also see the content search mechanism on the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/content-search

The advanced search is using the filter icons under activity click on the filter icon.

[image]

or you can use the \ or @ mentions in the top search bar. This will take you right to the conversations

[image]

Export your chat session is not yet implemented. Please vote on the user voice below

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/32184895-export-your-conversations-to-a-document

But if you enabled the content search then your chat history can be downloaded after performing Content Search in Compliance & Security center by Office 365 admins. Your personal chat history is actually saved in your mailbox, which means it can be exported as other mailbox items by admins.

Hope this helps